# String Concatentation

Tags: java

I have the following code and the return is confusing me. I am new to java and not exactly sure why it is returning the way it is. Any help would be great.

When the data has `PE846` and `A846` it returns `engine`, `ambo` and `engineambo`.  I'm looking to return only `engineambo`.

```
    String soundString = "";

    if (data.contains("PE846")) {
        soundString += "engine";
        betaString = "Engine : ";
        sign = engine;
    }
    if (data.contains("A846")) {
        soundString += "ambo";
        betaString += "Ambo : ";
        sign = ambo;
    }
    if (data.contains("MD846")) {
        soundString += "medic";
        betaString += "Medic";
        sign = medic;
    }

    log.info(betaString + " Alerted");

    {
        new AudioPlayer("sounds/" + soundString + ".wav").start();
        log.info(soundString);
    }
```

Comment: Your code sample doesn't even include the return.

Comment: You mean the contents of soundString?

Comment: What do you mean be it returning 3 elements? A method cannot return more than one. Please explain.

Comment: I think he means the output of log with "returns"

Comment: Is there any other code we need to be aware of?  Could you include the complete function, in particular the bit that returns the string...

Comment: @openscript, next time please don't make the format of the code worse than the original post.

Comment: Please indent the code to make it clearer

Comment: I come to this site because I am learning with a book and am self taught.  If I dont understand Im hoping someone can guide me to what Im doing wrong.  I was under the impression this was a Q & A site, if Im correct I dont think I deserve the downgrades that I continue to get.  If Im wrong I apologize and will not seek any more advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try tracing through your code line-by-line.  If it contains PE846 and A846 (but not MD846), then it will run the first two conditional blocks, thereby executing as follows:

```
if (data.contains("PE846")){   // The string does contain PE846, per your question
    soundString += "engine";   // soundString = "" + "engine" = "engine"
    betaString = "Engine : ";  // betaString = "Engine : "
    sign = engine;             // sign = engine
}
if (data.contains("A846")){    // The string does contain A846, per your question
    soundString += "ambo";     // soundString = "engine" + "ambo"
    betaString += "Ambo : ";   // betaString = "Engine : " + "Ambo : " = "Engine : Ambo : "
    sign = ambo;               // sign = ambo (overwriting the previous value, "engine")
}
if (data.contains("MD846")){   // The string does not contain MD846, per your question
    soundString += "medic";    // not executed
    betaString += "Medic";     // not executed
    sign = medic;              // not executed
}

log.info(betaString + " Alerted");  // betaString + " Alerted" => "Engine : Ambo : Alerted"
{
    new AudioPlayer("sounds/"+ soundString +".wav").start();
    log.info(soundString);          // soundString => "engineambo"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting the code to not have variables which get reassigned so often.  The `final` keyword will prevent a second assignment of a variable, and that will get rid of the need to check your entire program flow to see if previous assignments have an impact on latter assignments.  In addition, avoid the use of `+=` unless you truly mean to add data to existing data.

Also, if you set something to the "correct value" don't continue to possibly change it if the other values are not a possibility.

Something like

```
String mystring;

if (data.contains("MD846")) {
  mystring = "medic";
} else if (data.contains("A846")) {
  mystring = "ambo";
}
```

cannot set mystring to"medicambo" just because data was set to "MD846A846".

Answer (score 0):

If your data contains PE846-A846, it simply contains PE, A, and PE && A. You should first check for PE && A in one if statement, and if that fails, check for each of them seperately

Answer (score 0):

The method `contains` is not suitable to look for substrings, because it takes a `CharSequence` object and not a `String` object.

The best option in this case is to replace the `contains` method for `indexOf` from class String.